# Unable to use ASP.NET Core identity by using ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

We are looking to migrate our existing application to ASP.NET Core 2.2 , with the reference on the same I am facing some challenges

In the existing system we are using membership but in ASP.NET Core, it is identity; in identity, the default connection is Entity Framework. Can we switch to use ADO.NET connectivity, because we need to migrate the existing data? We are not looking to have Entity Framework in this project.

Please help and suggest

Comment: This is going to take some work.  I have my own custom solution.  I do not even use any of the identity tables.  I have my own ADO.NET backend behind a web api.  But for startes take a look at these links:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: Check this one out as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: You will need to implement the interfaces needed for your scenario.